# How do I write a Django ORM query that searches for a value that is close but doesn't exceed a certain other value?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, orm

I'm using Python 3.7 with Postgres 9.5.  I would like to write a Django ORM query if possible.  I have the below model

```
class PageStat(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    elapsed_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What I would like to do is write a query that, for a given article and elapsed time (an integer in seconds), I would like to write a query taht returns the PageStat object with the greatest elapsed time value that doesn't exceed the argument.  So, for example, if my table had these values

```
article_id      elapsed_time
==================
1           10
1           20
1           30
2           15
```

And I did a search with article ID "1" and elapsed time" 15", I would like to get back the first row (where article_id = 1 and elapsed_time = 10), since "10" is the greatest value that is still less than 15.  I know how to write a query for just finding the stat with the article,

```
PageStat.objects.filter(article=article)
```

but I don't know how to factor in the time value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the `QuerySet` by `elapsed_time`, and then select the first one, like:

```
slowest_pagestat = PageStat.objects.filter(
    article=my_article,
    elapsed_time__lte=threshold
).order_by('-elapsed_time').first()
```

This will return a `PageState` object if such `PageState` exists, and `None` otherwise.

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT pagestat.*
FROM pagestat
WHERE pagestat.article_id = 1
AND   pagestat.elapsed_time <= 15
ORDER BY pagestat.elapsed_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

with `1` the primary key of `my_article`, and `15` the `threshold`.

Comment: Will this return a full result set to Python adn then Python filters out one row or does a query get generated that only returns one row?  I'm wondering if performance will be an issue if my db contains thousands of rows.

Comment: @Dave: noo... `.first()` adds a `LIMIT 1` to the query, and thus will retrieve (at most) one record. Django's querysets do *not* filter in Python, these construct SQL queries. Although ORM technology can of course still improve (write better queries), for such simple ones, it is more the databae side that needs to optimize the query.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
PageStat.objects.filter(elapsed_time__lte=20)
```

There are also:

```
lt - less than 
gte - greater than equal
gt - greater than
etc
```

Comment: Regarding your answer, won't this return all rows that are less than or equal to 20?  I only want the one that is closest and less than.  In other words, the result set shoudl contain at most one row.

Comment: Yep, my answer is regarding the <= part. I think William gave you the full solution to your question.